# Display of data on highcharts

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am developing some highcharts design, the requirement is displaying the day today work status, for that i am using column chart,

[image]

For each day there can be 2 status, Met or Not met,

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        data: {
            table: 'datatable'
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
            type:'date',
            series: {
                tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                min: Date.UTC(2016, 4, 31),
                max: Date.UTC(2016, 11, 6),
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                    month: '%b \'%y',
                    year: '%Y'
                }
            },
        }],
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I am using something like this, i am confused how to proceed.

Comment: Columns required number values, how do you want to show met/not met information in the chart?

Comment: We'll need something more specific. I am not seeing an actual question in this post. The image you linked to looks like a simple table rather than a column chart, and your code is incomplete.